# Javascript: How can quotation mark be added to individual values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I have a function that retrieve and display values of a csv file.

function

```
var IDArr = [];
var fileInput = document.getElementById("csv");

readFile = function() {
  console.log("file uploaded")
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    // document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result;

    // I assigned the IDs retrieved from the CSV file to an array named keys
    IDArr.push(reader.result);
    // var keys = [reader.result];
    var promises = IDArr.map(function(key) {
      return firebase.database().ref("/Agents/").child(key).once("value");
    });
    // read the data from the database for each ID
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(snapshots) {
      snapshots.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.key + ": " + snapshot.val());
      });
    });
  };

  // start reading the file. When it is done, calls the onload event defined above.
  reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
};

if (fileInput) {
  fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);
}
```

the above function producess the image below

[image]

i need to put a quotation mark around each ID value and separate each with a comma. So for example I want to create a new array that looks like this "75799757","9744710", "79989647", "99029704" how can I implement this?

Comment: At first, split by space, then shift the first value out, and finally iterate the array, and  convert the numbers to string.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want the values in your array to be strings.  I can't see how adding quotes and commas to array elements is that useful.

Comment: @James I want to use the format for looping through firebase database but how can I convert it to strings ?

Comment: Use `Number.toString` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = "ID 75799757 9744710 79989647 9902970";
let arr = str.split(" ").splice(1);
let result = arr.map((val) => '"'+val+'"').reduce((a,b) => a+','+b);
```

after this the result looks like this `"75799757","9744710","79989647","99029704"`

Comment: the current format does not have quotation mark around the IDs, it is in arr without quotation mark

Comment: the end result string contains a single string with double quotes within it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = ...;
var parts = str.split(" ");
str = "'" + parts[0] + "'";
for (var i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
  str += ",'" + parts[i] + "'";
}
```

Comment: it does not separate the IDs this is what it produce   'ID
75799757
9744710
79989647
99029704'